# 2 row carousel in Owl Carousel 2

Tags: carousel, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am using owl carousel 2 plugin to build a carousel. I want it to be with 2 rows (with 3 items in each row) on screens bigger than 480px and 1 row (with 1 item) only on screen smaller than 480px.

[image]

Is it doable?

Below is the code used.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop:true,
margin:10,
nav:true,
responsive:{
0:{
items:1
},
480:{
items:3,
},
768:{
items:5
}
}
})
});
</script>
```